# Google map search bar resize in GWT

Tags: search, gwt, google-maps, resize

I have a gwt application that uses the map api for a mapWidget. I added the integrated search for the map with setGoogleBarEnabled(true). It works fine, but the input field is 6px height.
How can I resize it?
Thanks
Balint

Answer (score 2):

The Google Search Bar should be 15px in height by default, as far as I can understand by inspecting the DOM of a Google Map with the search bar enabled.

This is how the search bar looks in the DOM:

```
<div id=":0:formId" class="gels-form-div">
   <img id=":0:logoId" class="gels-logo" src="http://www.google.com/uds/modules/elements/localsearch/logo_66x22.png">
   <input id=":0:inputId" class="gels-input" type="text" name="search" title="search" value="search the map" style="width: 153px; ">
   <input id=":0:buttonId" class="gels-button" type="submit" value="Search" title="search">
</div>
```

Make sure that your application is not overriding the height of the `gels-input` class. If this does not help, you may want to override the height yourself with:

```
input.gels-input {
    height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I tried to override it in standard.css but it dont works.
Any other idea?